# How do I pass a dynamic URL from XML into an onClick Mouse Event in ActionScript 3?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm loading the XML in, and I'm able to read the XML nodes into text fields in my flash. It is also loading the URL, but the last one from the loop. It's not loading the one that I click on. I tried using `event.target`, but that is not working. I'm pretty close to figuring it out, I'm just not sure where to look.

```
// loads xml 
var xml:XML = new XML();
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(audioPlaylist));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
        xml = XML(evt.target.data);
        xmlList = xml.children();
        trace(xmlList);
        trackLength = xmlList.children().children().length();
        trace(trackLength);

        for(var i:int = 0; i < trackLength; i++) {
            trace(i);
            var track:Playlist_item = new Playlist_item();
            track.y = i * 28;

            track.playlist_text.text = xmlList.children().track[i].toString();
            trackURL = xmlList.children().track[i].@rel.toString();

            trace(trackURL);

            playlist_container.addChild(track);
            track.buttonMode = true;
            track.mouseChildren=false;

            track.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onCarHover);
            track.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onCarOut);
            track.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickLoadData);

        }

}

function onCarHover(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.gotoAndStop(6);
}

function onCarOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.gotoAndStop(10);
}

function onClickLoadData(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play(trackURL);
}
```

---

I'm getting closer, I managed to create an array, with an index value - so now I can choose different URLs from the array to play, but I'm still unsure how to target the one that I'm clicking directly on and have that play.

Here is my updated code:

```
// xml variables
var xmlList:XMLList;
var trackLength:Number;
var trackURL;
var trackNum:Number = -1;
var tracksArray:Array = new Array();


// loads xml 
var xml:XML = new XML();
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(audioPlaylist));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
        xml = XML(evt.target.data);
        xmlList = xml.children();
        trace(xmlList);
        trackLength = xmlList.children().children().length();

        while (trackNum < trackLength) {
            trackNum = trackNum + 1;
            trace(trackNum);

            var track:Playlist_item = new Playlist_item();
            track.y = trackNum * 28;
            playlist_container.addChild(track);

            track.buttonMode = true;
            track.mouseChildren=false;

            track.playlist_text.text = xmlList.children().track[trackNum].toString();
            //trackURL = xmlList.children().track[trackNum].@rel.toString();

            tracksArray[trackNum] = xmlList.children().track[trackNum].@rel.toString();

            track.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onCarHover);
            track.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onCarOut);
            track.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickLoadData);

        }   

}

function onCarHover(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.gotoAndStop(6);
}

function onCarOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.gotoAndStop(10);
}

function onClickLoadData(event:MouseEvent):void {

    trace(tracksArray[5]);

    trace(event.target.trackNum);
    ns.play(tracksArray[5]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have made this hard on yourself.  I may be incorrect as it is hard to traverse through the code you have presented.  The concept of an XML playlist and clicking a display object to play sounds is quite easy and I will demonstrate.

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
    <item title="Song 1" path="audio/song1.mp3" />
    <item title="Song 2" path="audio/song2.mp3" />
    <item title="Song 3" path="audio/song3.mp3" />
    <item title="Song 4" path="audio/song4.mp3" />
    <item title="Song 5" path="audio/song5.mp3" />
    <item title="Song 6" path="audio/song6.mp3" />
</xml>
```

The ActionScript 3 code

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class DocumentClass extends Sprite
    {
        private var _urlLoader:URLLoader;
        private var _urlRequest:URLRequest;
        private var _xml:XML;
        private var _xmlList:XMLList;

        public function DocumentClass():void
        {
            _urlLoader = new URLLoader();
            _urlRequest = new URLRequest();
            _urlRequest.url = 'path/to/playlist.xml';

            _urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoaded);
            _urlLoader.load(_urlRequest);
        }
        private function onXMLLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            _xml = new XML(e.target.data);
            _xmlList = new XMLList(_xml.item);

            //We use the index in the XML object as its ID. (The XML object/List is an array);
            for(var i:int = 0; i < _xmlList.length(); i++)
            {
                var s:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
                addChild(s);
                s.mouseChildren = false;

                var tf:TextField = new TextField();
                tf.text = _xmlList[i].@title;
                tf.y = i * 12 + 20; //Seperates the textfields by 12 px starting at y:20;
                s.path = _xmlList[i].@path;
                s.addChild(tf);
                s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onSDown);
            }
        }
        private var onSDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest(e.target.path));
            s.play();
        }
    }
}
```

So we load the XML into our document class.  We loop through the xml length(); many times, which is how many children are in the XML Object.  For each loop, or child, we create a MovieClip, add a textfield to it, label the textfield, then add a property of "path" (xmlList[int].@path) to the containing movieclip, with a value of that current childs path attribute from the xml.  The MouseEvent is regarded to the MovieClip and we tell the textfield inside to not receive mouse input.

I hope that this helps, wrapping the text in a MovieClip we can add properties to it that can be accessed by the event method through the target which is s.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem!

My solution was to create an array which stored all the URLs by `trackNum`, then create instance names inside my while loop. Then, I used `event.target.name` with substring to trim off the text and leave me with just the numbers. It works awesome!

```
// xml variables
var xmlList:XMLList;
var trackLength:Number;
var trackURL;
var trackNum:Number = -1;
var tracksArray:Array = new Array();


// loads xml 
var xml:XML = new XML();
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(audioPlaylist));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
        xml = XML(evt.target.data);
        xmlList = xml.children();
        trace(xmlList);
        trackLength = xmlList.children().children().length();

        while (trackNum < trackLength) {
            trackNum = trackNum + 1;

            var track:Playlist_item = new Playlist_item();
            track.y = trackNum * 28;
            playlist_container.addChild(track);
            track.name = "track" + [trackNum];

            trace(track);

            track.buttonMode = true;
            track.mouseChildren=false;

            track.playlist_text.text = xmlList.children().track[trackNum].toString();
            //trackURL = xmlList.children().track[trackNum].@rel.toString();

            tracksArray[trackNum] = xmlList.children().track[trackNum].@rel.toString();

            track.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onCarHover);
            track.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onCarOut);
            track.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickLoadData);

        }   

}

function onCarHover(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.gotoAndStop(6);
}

function onCarOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.gotoAndStop(10);
}

function onClickLoadData(event:MouseEvent):void {

    //trace(tracksArray[5]);

    trace(event.target.name.substr(5));

    ns.play(tracksArray[event.target.name.substr(5)]);
}
```